# Performance: combn on large data.table

Tags: r, performance, data.table

Lets start with some generated data which are pretty realistic:

```
tmp <- data.table(
  label  = sprintf( "X%03d", 1:500),
  start  = sample( 50:950, 500, replace=TRUE ),
  length = round( 20 *  rf( rep(1, 500), 5, 5 ), 0 )
)
DT <- tmp[ , list( t = seq( start, length.out=length ) ), by = label ]
DT[ , I := sample(1:100, 1) * dbeta( seq(from=0,to=1, length.out=length(t)), sample(3:6,1), sample(5:10,1) ), by = label ]
DT <- DT[ I > 1E-2 ]
```

`DT` represents time series data for (in this case) 500 labels:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot( DT[ t %between% c(100,200) ], aes( x = t, y = I, group = label ) ) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

I want to correlate the data by all label pairs, given that they have a sufficient overlap. This is my approach:

```
# feel free to use just a subset here
labs <- DT[ , unique( label )  ][1:50]
# is needed for fast intersecting
setkey( DT, t )
# just needed for tracking progress    
count <- 0
progress <- round(seq( from = 1, to = length(labs) * (length(labs) -1) / 2, length.out=100 ),0)

corrs <- 
  combn( labs, m=2, simplify=TRUE, minOverlap = 5, FUN = function( x, minOverlap ) {

    # progress
    count <<- count + 1
    if( count %in% progress ){
      cat( round( 100*count/max(progress),0 ), ".." )
    }

    # check overlap and correlate
    a <- DT[label == x[1]]
    b <- DT[label == x[2]]        
    iscectT <- intersect( a[ , t], b[ , t] )
    n  <- length(iscectT)
    if( n >= minOverlap ){
      R <- cor( a[J(iscectT)][, I], b[J(iscectT)][, I] )
      return( c( x[1], x[2], n, min(iscectT), max(iscectT), R) )
    }
    else{
      # only needed because of simplify = TRUE
      return( rep(NA, 6)  )
    }
  })
```

This works pretty fine, but is much slower than expected. In the particular case this would take up to 10 minutes on my machine.

Any help on improving the performance of this approach is highly appreciated. Questions which came to my mind:

- Do I have to expect any side effects concerning on `DT`if I would deploy one of R's parallelization mechanisms, e.g. `foreach`? Is there a parallelization interface for `data.table` as there is for example for `plyr`?
- Is there a way of using `combn` with `simplify = FALSE` without having horrible runtimes the longer the process goes. I assume that a lot of `list` copying takes place because increasing `list` capacities.
- Is there anything I can do on the algorithmic side to make this faster?

Comment: Have you profiled your code? I would probably not use the `FUN` argument of `combn` here, but calculate the combinations and do the rest with appropriate joins.

Comment: OMG! @Roland I just didn't dare to join the tables on the label combinations. However, it just works instantaneously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Roland suggested in his comment, using `combn` just to calculate the combinations of labels and then perform directly joins on the `data.table`, is magnitudes faster:

```
corrs <- as.data.frame(do.call( rbind, combn(labs, m=2, simplify = FALSE) ), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
names(corrs) <- c("a", "b")
setDT(corrs)

setkey(DT, label)
setkey( corrs, a )

corrs <- corrs[ DT, nomatch = 0, allow.cartesian = TRUE]
setkey(corrs, b, t)
setkey(DT, label, t)

corrs <- corrs[ DT, nomatch = 0 ]
corrs[ , overlap := .N >= minOverlap , by = list(a,b) ]
corrs <- corrs[ (overlap) ]
corrs <- corrs[ ,list( start = min(t), end = max(t), R = cor(I,I.1) ), by = list(a,b) ]
```